# Redirect Site Wide, Exclude Page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all pages on my website to another page:

harryfelton.host56.com -> harryfelton.host56.com/webisteDown.php

The thing is that either it doesnt redirect or it redirects the output page and causes a loop, I want to be able to put that in the .htaccess file and have any page on the website redirect to the websiteDown.php... Another problem I got was that there was no css styling on the page after redirect, Even though it is there if I go there myself, is is the extra '/' I think it is because if I add that it looses styles, But anyway, Anyone know how to do the redirecting?

### Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(webisteDown\.php|.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ webisteDown.php [L,NC,R]
```

This rule redirects to `/webisteDown.php` if request is not for `webisteDown.php` OR any css, js, images files.

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt work... The webpage at http://harryfelton.host56.com/www/harryfelton.host56.com/webisteDown.php has resulted in too many redirects. is what chrome is telling me.. The URL when that error appears is: http://harryfelton.host56.com/www/harryfelton.host56.com/webisteDown.php

My .htaccess:
`codeErrorDocument 404 /notFound.php
ErrorDocument 403 /noAccess.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(webisteDown\.php|.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ webisteDown.php [L,NC,R]`

Comment: Also, Is it possible to make this work anywhere on the site, So no matter where I go it will redirect to the websiteDown.php page, I dont want people being able to just go `www.harryfelton.host56.com/index` and bypass the redirect... Unless thats already how its supposed to work...

Comment: Nevermind, I just changed it to: `RewriteRule !^(websiteDown\.php|.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ http://www.harryfelton.host56.com/websiteDown.php [L,NC,R]` Thank you very much sir!